# How to enable and use code folding in Vim?

Tags: vim

How can I enable and **do** code folding in Vim?

Do I have to change anything in `~/.vimrc`?

I type <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and nothing happens.

Here is an article about folding: [Code folding in Vim](https://web.archive.org/web/20161016081350/http://smartic.us/2009/04/06/code-folding-in-vim/).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No you don't have to put the command from the page you linked to in your `~/.vimrc`, you can just type them after issuing `:` in `vim` to get the command prompt.

However if you put the lines:

```
set foldmethod=indent   
set foldnestmax=10
set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=2
```

as indicated in the link you gave, in your `~/.vimrc`, you don't have to type them every time you want to use folding in a file. The `set nofoldenable` makes sure that when opening, files are "normal", i.e. not folded.

Comment: I have a code which is written by C, So the courser in on the one of its functions. I press <kbd>esc</kbd> to go to the command so, after : , I write zc and nothing happen.

Comment: @alex the zc you should not type after `:`. You type the `set` commands after the prompt you get when typing `:`. The `zc` you type when you can freely move the cursor, just like you would use `zt` to get the text the cursor is on to the top of the current screen.

Answer (score 104):

## Fold by default

Vim's default folding method is `manual` meaning that the folds are created manually; otherwise, there is no fold to be closed or opened using <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> as you described. But, you can create a fold by <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`{motion}` in *Normal* mode or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in *Visual* mode; e.g. <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> creates a fold for current line and the next following one in *Normal* mode.

## Fold by `indent`

The accepted answer, by @Anthon, describes how to set folding method to `indent`; i.e. folding are defined by the level of indentations.

## Fold by `syntax`

In a more convenient way, folds can be created automatically based on the language syntax of the current buffer. If you are using a programming language, let's call it *L*, and you have folding definition of *L* (e.g. you have installed a Vim plugin in which the folding information of *L* is defined; such as *[c.vim](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/c-vim-the-thing-itself)* for C/C++, or *[python-mode](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/python-mode)* for Python), you just need to set folding method to `syntax`:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

That's it. The most useful commands for working with folds are:

- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> opens a fold at the cursor.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> opens all folds at the cursor.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> closes a fold at the cursor.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> increases the `foldlevel` by one.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> closes all open folds.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> decreases the `foldlevel` by one.
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> decreases the `foldlevel` to zero -- all folds will be open.

Answer (score 19):

You don't have to use it systematically: I usually manually select folds by the motion or section. For example, folding a paragraph is `zfip` and folding the next 20 lines is `zf20j`. Use `za` to toggle and `zd` to remove.

This requires a little more work but allows your folding to reflect the task at hand.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable `folding` in current session like @Anthon's answer. But if you want make it permanent, you must setting at least this line in `.vimrc` to folding work:

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

`indent` is kind of folding, you can see more from `:help foldmethod`

```
'foldmethod' 'fdm'      string (default: "manual")
                        local to window
                        {not in Vi}
                        {not available when compiled without the +folding
                        feature}
        The kind of folding used for the current window.  Possible values:
        fold-manual     manual      Folds are created manually.
        fold-indent     indent      Lines with equal indent form a fold.
        fold-expr       expr        'foldexpr' gives the fold level of a line.
        fold-marker     marker      Markers are used to specify folds.
        fold-syntax     syntax      Syntax highlighting items specify folds.
        fold-diff       diff        Fold text that is not changed.
```

Now, everytime you open a file with `vim`, you can see the code is folded by the method you was set. Then you can use `za`, `zc`, `zo`.

Comment: There is no need to use the vimrc, I never did that as I use folding only occasionally

Comment: @Anthon: Oh, of course. I will add more information in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone wants to change default fold method and stop auto-folding when new file opens, Add this code in your vim config file below:

```
setlocal foldmethod=syntax         
setlocal foldlevelstart=99
```

`setlocal foldmethod` is to change the default `Manual` fold method and `foldlevelstart` to stop auto-folding when the files are opening.
You can change the value to customize the auto-folding level. check the documentation here: [https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'foldlevelstart'](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27foldlevelstart%27)

Answer (score 3):

The answers above are wonderful. Thanks for helping me! 
Why not add this one:

```
nnoremap <space> @=((foldclosed(line('.')) < 0) ? 'zc' : 'zo')<CR>
```

Much more convenient way: using  `space` instead of `z + c` and `z + o`!

Comment: Not sure why you were down-voted, this was useful for me thanks!

Comment: This is more complicated than it needs to be. There is already a mapping (`za`) to toggle the current fold (close it if it's open and open it if it's closed). You can still map <space> to za if you want, of course.